Where can I find an EGA demo by IBM that created a full screen animation by redefining the EGA character glyphs?
It was an IBM demo of the EGA's ability to show arbitrary text characters, like Chinese or hieroglyphics.
It was a full screen animation of a waterfall and a brook and trees with waving leaves. but it was actually just a screen full of static text mode characters, all being redefined several times a second. In theory, the animation could be arbitrarily long.
While EGA did 16 colors, the demo had to be monochrome because all the dots in a given text character had to be the same color.
Where can I watch that again?

I remember reading about that demo; I think it was called Fantasy Land or something similar.  To date, I'd been curious about it but never seen it nor video, but a web search found https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/demo/ibm/ega/ which may be what you're after.

Amazing! == FantasyLand uses the EGA’s switchable fonts to create animation effects. The program loads several copies of a custom font into memory, and an interrupt service routine cycles through the copies every four system clock ticks. Certain characters in the custom font have slight differences across the copies so that, when cycled, they give the illusion of motion–a dragon flaps his wings, smoke billows from a chimney, grass waves in the wind. By tying the animation directly to the system’s 8253 timer interrupt, font switching happens continuously, independent of CPU speed.

But mine was a different demo.

Am I missing something or is this what many 8-bit games did, especially on the C64?

Like @supercat above, I was convinced it was FantasyLand too! But if it isn't, I'll keep looking.

Are you sure that it was IBM who made this demo?

@ajm Yes I'm pretty sure, but please don't spend your time looking for it unless you have absolutely nothing better to do.

@JessFuckett On the contrary - these retrocomputing rabbit holes are always fun to go down! I'm at work right now but will do some sleuthing in the evening.

@AJM It was a static scene but didn't scroll. the entire thing was green, and it had a waterfall flowing into a stream that flowed to offscreen

@MissUnderstands Could this in fact have been made by the graphics card vendor, as opposed to IBM themselves?

@AJM I'm almost certain it was IBM because I'm remembering thinking the same thing I did when I watched those nvidia  technology demos many years later:  only IBM,  the people who invented this new EGA, would know how to squeeze such elegant behavior out of it.

Do you remember which year you saw this demo?

'fraid not exactly.
